# Email Vyatta Log File

Tags: email, debian, vyatta

I have a vyatta set up as the top layer of security on a website.

The vyatta is running IPS which then outputs to a log file.

What I would like to do is to set the Vyatta to email me this log file daily so I will be aware of any events without having to physically check on the box.

The vyatta is connected straight to the internet so it can access my webserver via IP.

I can guess I will have to create a cron job to do this but I am not sure how to send an email from the vyatta.

FYI Vyatta is based on Debian 6.